# pronunciation of Robinson Crusoe in French

Tags: anglais, prononciation, orthographe, noms-propres

Daniel Defoe wrote Robinson Crusoe. Why is Crusoe pronounced in French as Cru-so-ay and Defoe as De-foh, whereas Crusoe is pronounced in English as Kroo-soh?

Comment: This doesn't give the ultimate reason, but it's because whoever translated it spelled *Crusoe* as *Crusoé*, while they spelled *Defoe* as *Defoe*. The pronunciations follow the standard rules of French pronunciation, given these spellings. [See amazon.fr webpage for Robinson Crusoé](https://www.amazon.com/Robinson-Crusoé/dp/2848013672).

Comment: Hmm, which came first, the chicken or the egg?

Comment: In the earliest French translations, it was spelled Crusoe, not Crusoé.

Comment: @jkien Please note we also have "Ivanhoé" like that. Maybe the publisher or any other person not necessary knowing the original pronunciation décided to add an acute accent on the final e for the sake of clarity for the french audience. (oe is a rare final for words). I guess there wasn't the same concern for the author's name.

Comment: The different pronunciation for the same termination on different proper nouns is sometimes a mistery. As an example from south of France, local people mock Parisians when they pronounce the ending "s" of the city of "Aubenas", but a few miles away, the city airfield is on the locality of "Lanas", where the "s" is not mute.

Comment: @Graffito AubenaS? En Ardèche? Ah non! :-)

Comment: @Graffito Aubena se prononce comme Pari, Cassi ou Chamoni :-) On peut en revanche se poser des questions sur Reim*s* qui ne rime pas avec Amien...

Comment: @jkien As to your comment: "In the earliest French translations, it was spelled Crusoe, not Crusoé": I don't think this is relevant: first because as you can see in the [1721 edition](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k9606681n/f26.item) (the very 1st edition of the very 1st translation of the book) Crusoe is in italics, which could mean it the translator did not want to translate it. But more relevant to my mind is that accents are not always printed even on words that usually were written with one.

Comment: In this [later edition](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6487978m/f15.item) ( 1877 ) all accents are printed, Crusoe is  Crusoé (even when capitalized) and de Foë also has a diacritical sign. It seems that the diaeresis only occurs when written as 2 words, but I've checked very thoroughly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In English, -oe is an unremarkable word ending that can be pronounced in a variety of ways, but typically rhyming with *foe*, *roe*, *toe*, … pronounced /əʊ/ or /oʊ/.

The vowel /ʊ/ does not exist in French, and the closest vowel /u/ can't be used as the semi-vowel that ends a diphthong. So there is no natural way to convey the approximate pronunciation of the English word in French.

No native French word ends with -oe, and in all native French words that contain -oe-, the pronunciation of the -e- is determined by the following consonant. So a name ending on -oe would look weird, and a French speaker would wonder how to pronounce it. Is it a schwa /ə/? This sound normally only occurs after a consonant, as a weakening of a different sound (and tends to be silent in most dialects of modern French, but somewhat less so a few centuries ago). The name “Crusoe”, in French, is unescapably exotic.

No native French word ends with -oé, but a few words contain -oé- as a group of vowels. It is immediately clear how to pronounce it: the letter *é* is always pronounced /e/ no matter what's around it, and this leaves /o/ (or /ɔ/, but that's often a free variation) for the o. The name “Crusoé”, in French, is not native, but looks natural.

For a character that the reader should be able to identify with, in French, “*Robinson Crusoe*” is not quite right: the reader stumbles over the end. “*Robinson Crusoé*” works fine.

Comment: Then why is it different for the name of the author, Defoe?

Comment: There is one now: *[canoé](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cano%C3%A9)*.

Comment: @jkien The author's name is not translated. And the reader doesn't care how it's pronounced.

Comment: @jlliagre *Canoë* (*canoé* since 1990) appeared in the French language a couple of centuries after Crusoe. One could easily imagine the spelling of *canoë* was copied from Crusoë. Just an aside...

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' I was trying to find early translations of *The life & adventures of*... and came upon [the 1st one](https://fr.linkedin.com/pulse/robinson-cruso%C3%A9-premi%C3%A8re-%C3%A9dition-en-fran%C3%A7ais-1720-christian-gasch) with no accents on the cover, capital letters so no way to tell. But [this 19th c. one](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6541883v?rk=64378;0) with *de Foë*, and then found more 19th century spelling of *de Foë* (seems to be *oë* only when in 2 words).

Comment: On the way I came upon this [1797 bilingual edition](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k1067186v/f19.item), off topic but funny enough to point out.

Answer (score 0):

The french words ending in -oe are usually spelled « oé »; the word « canoé », although a [borrowing from English](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cano%C3%A9) has been frenchified. As "Crusoe" became a household word in France, whereas "Defoe" did not, this is possibly why the accent has been added. "Defoe" has no accent because English family names are not frenchified.

words ending in oé in French : Arsinoé, Ivanhoé, Cloé, Noé, , canoé, zoé

Comment: Arsinoé, très courant :-)

Comment: Note that *canoé*, the only substantive of the list, is written *canoë* according to the traditional spelling.